# ADT unable to render activity layout xml file

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, adt

[image: Example Image]

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="prajjwal.app.myfreight.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

I'm getting a java.lang.NullPointerException for some reason. I just updated my SDK build to 24.4.1, using Android 6.0 (API level 23) on Eclipse Mars.2.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please provide your Layout xml file!

Comment: It says it can't find a specific class. I'm sure it's in my computer, how do I go about "fixing the build path" ?

Comment: Did you not close your <RelativeLayout> Tag?

Answer (score 0):

shift to android studio as there won't be any technical support available for eclipse